# How to correctly style and apply hover for infinitely nested nav in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the infinite structure working, but I can not seem to get it to correctly apply hovers to display each sublist correctly.

```js
export default function InfiniteNav({ links }){

    function Links(props) {
        const { link } = props
        const { title, subLinks, path } = link

        return (
            <li className={`navItem`}>
                <Link to={path} >
                    {title}
                </Link>
                {subLinks && <ul className={`navLinks`}>
                    {subLinks.map((slink, i) => <Links key={i} link={slink} />)}
                </ul>}
            </li>
        )
    }

    return (
        <nav className="navContainer">
            <ul className="mainNav">
                {links.map((link, i) => <Links key={i} link={link} />)}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

This will render a static nav with all the list and sub list displayed. What I want to do is hide all sublist until their parent is hovered over. Then you would be able to keep hovering over parents down the tree displaying their list (if they have one).

Problems I run into are that when I leave one parent to hover one of it's children in the list it disappears. I am trying to use onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave but not sure if that is the correct path so I'm not going to include that code to detour anyone.

Comment: have you tried using the onHover listener?

Answer (score 1):

a css approach for this:

```
.navItem:not(:hover) .navLinks {
  display: none;
}
```